# Invoke an Android App from a WebPage

Tags: android

Hi 
  Is it possible to invoke an Android App from a Web Page that i am displaying on the phone browser to the user. I know that this is possible from an another Android App using Intents. But i am not sure if this is possible from a WebPage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Intent filters with the `BROWSABLE` category will let you launch an application using a URI scheme. Inside your `<activity>`, add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="myprotocol" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

and set up the action and categories how you want, and change the scheme to something relevant to your application.

Then inside your webpage, you can link to your application with

```
<a href="myprotocol://">test link</a>
```

Comment: If you find an answer is correct, make sure to accept it by clicking the check mark to the left!

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a intent filter for a particular URI within your Activity:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

That way, that activity will be called when a corresponding link is clicked. By using a custom scheme you'll make sure that your app is the only one responding.

It's the same way the android market responds to market links.

Comment: How can i thank you both. You are so good. Thanks for the quick reply. I don't know that this is possible, i was thinking a webpage is completely different from the android framework and hence its not possible to invoke an Android App which sits in a completely different context. I am proved wrong.